# Error in debugging "free(): double free detected in tcache 2"

Tags: c, hashmap, free

I understand the meaning of this error: something was freed twice. But when I step through my code I can't see the logical/syntax error really. And I can't debug as this error prevents me from running my debugger. Here's my code, any thoughts?

This code is meant to free a hashmap I've created.

```
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        while (table[i] != NULL)
        {
            node *temp = table[i]->next;
            free(table[i]);
            table[i] = temp;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The cause of the error is likely not in the code you show, it only exhibits the symptoms of an error elsewhere. Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: When working with things like lists, I suggest you take the smallest input set which triggers the problem, and while debugging *all* of your code draw the lists you create using pencil and paper. When a list is modified, erase and redraw the list on paper as well. That way it will become very easy to see when and where something happens that shouldn't happen.

Comment: I don't know.  Wild guess:  I suppose if `table[i]` has the same address as `node *temp` at any time for any reason after the 1st `free()`, I could imagine a scenario where `free()` could get called twice for *that* address.  Hence, a fix might entail checking the address of both to ensure they are different *before* calling `free()` -- or something in this neighborhood.

Comment: try using `valgrind --track-origins=yes -s ./your-program` to track down the bug.

Comment: Like, you know, depending on the design, I think there are many linked list designs which have node->next pointing to *this/current* node in scenarios -- near program start or near program finish -- when there is only one node in the list, isn't it true?  I reckon that if it's near program end and one node left,  then `free()` could get called twice on that node.